# Is there a way in .NET Framework to populate City name using RegionInfo or CultureInfo classes?

Tags: .net

I'm using this code to display Country names:

```
Shared Sub DisplayCountries()
            Dim lstCounTry As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            Dim ci As CultureInfo
            For Each ci In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                Dim ri As System.Globalization.RegionInfo = New System.Globalization.RegionInfo(ci.LCID)

                If Not lstCounTry.Contains(ri.EnglishName) Then
                    lstCounTry.Add(ri.EnglishName)
                End If
            Next

            lstCounTry.Sort()

            For Each item In lstCounTry
                Console.WriteLine(item)
            Next
        End Sub
```

Is there a way in .NET Framework to populate City name using same method?

Comment: No, .NET doesn't have a database of city names.  You'll have to provide your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no list of city names in the BCL.

As for using `RegionInfo` - a region may have many cities, so even if that data existed, you would still need a way to select one.

`CultureInfo` is an even poorer match - not all cultures have a single country associated with them (many have several).

You will need to implement something like this yourself.